# Вывод на экран двух элементов из функции по отдельности

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, print

Пытаюсь вывести из функции по отдельности два элемента.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

```
universities = [
    ['California Institute of Technology', 2174, 37704],
    ['Harvard', 19627, 39849],
    ['Massachusetts Institute of Technology', 10566, 40732],
    ['Princeton', 7802, 37000],
    ['Rice', 5879, 35551],
    ['Stanford', 19535, 40569],
    ['Yale', 11701, 40500]
]

def enrollment_stats():
    r = 0
    p = 0
    for u in universities:
        r += u[1]
        p += u[2]
    return r , p 
print(enrollment_stats())
```

---

Хотелось бы получить вот такой результат :

```
Total students: 77,285
Total tuition: $ 271,905
```

Comment: А сейчас что выводится? Если хочешь вывести "Total students", то где-то в одк должно быть написано "Total students". Функция твоя возвращает две переменные, ты их можешь присвоить двум разным переменным. Ты же просто выводишь полученный кортеж.

Comment: Переменный (в моем случае Total students ,Total tuition ) надо объявлять в теле функции или за пределами функции или в качестве аргумента функции  ? Я пытаюсь ссылаться на r,p .Но ничего не получается .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
universities = [
    ['California Institute of Technology', 2174, 37704],
    ['Harvard', 19627, 39849],
    ['Massachusetts Institute of Technology', 10566, 40732],
    ['Princeton', 7802, 37000],
    ['Rice', 5879, 35551],
    ['Stanford', 19535, 40569],
    ['Yale', 11701, 40500]
]

def enrollment_stats():
    r = 0
    p = 0
    for u in universities:
        r += u[1]
        p += u[2]
    return r , p 
    
print('Total students: {0:,}. \nTotal tuition : $ {1:,}'.format(* enrollment_stats()))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

> Он работает . Все хорошо. Но я еще не изучил метод форматирования `.format`. Хотелось бы как то попроще.

Попробуйте так:

```
universities = [
    ['California Institute of Technology', 2174, 37704],
    ['Harvard', 19627, 39849],
    ['Massachusetts Institute of Technology', 10566, 40732],
    ['Princeton', 7802, 37000],
    ['Rice', 5879, 35551],
    ['Stanford', 19535, 40569],
    ['Yale', 11701, 40500]
]

def enrollment_stats():
    r = 0
    p = 0
    for u in universities:
        r += u[1]
        p += u[2]
    return r , p 
    
total_students, total_tuition = enrollment_stats()                     # +++
print('Total students: ' + str(total_students )+'. \nTotal tuition : $ '+ str(total_tuition))
```

Comment: @andrew что не так в моем ответе?

Comment: Он работает . Все хорошо. Но я еще не  изучил метод форматирования .format. Хотелось бы как то попроще .

Comment: @andrew я добавил в ответ обновление, проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @andrew пожалуйста